# Python: (Working but slow) Import multiple CSV files, find unique identifiers, then search through original CSV lists for corresponding tuple value

Tags: python-3.x, csv, tuples, list-comprehension

I'm importing two sets of six csv files (each with 3 columns) and saving them into one list. My basic data structure is this (assuming 1 set of 2 csv files):

```
total =  [ [ ["Name", 6, 4.3],["Name2", 7, 5.5] ] [ ["Name3", 12, 5.7], ["Name4", 8, 9.2] ] ]
```

So total[0] is the entire first set of csv files (all six), total[0][0] is the first individual csv file from set 0, total[0][0][0] is the first entry, total[0][0][0][0] is the name of the identifier.

Next, I've flattened the list and made another list containing the unique names from all CSV files. My basic data structure is this (for each set of csv files):

```
unique = [ [ Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4 ] [Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4] ]
```

Done. So here's the tricky bit. What I want to do is make another list where I work through all unique Names and pull in corresponding tuple data from every CSV file saved in the list from total[0][0] to [0][6]. So every unique value should pull out 6 numbers.

Here's what I've got.

```
def CollectProteinInformation(total, unique):

spectralcount = []

for y in range(len(total)): #For every test set

    spectralcountbuffer = []

    for x in range(len(unique[y])): #for every unique value in set y
        spectralcountbuffer2 = []
        for i in range(len(total[y])): #for every csv file in state y
            SpectraIndex = next((q for q, n in enumerate(total[y][i]) if str(n[0]) == str(unique[y][x])), "N/A") # Go through the list and, using the unique ID, find if it's in the total list.
            if SpectraIndex != "N/A":
                spectralcountbuffer2.append(total[y][i][SpectraIndex][1])
            else:
                spectralcountbuffer2.append(0.1) # <-- Spectral Fraction insert here
        spectralcountbuffer.append(spectralcountbuffer2)
    spectralcount.append(spectralcountbuffer)

print(spectralcount)
return spectralcount
```

This works fine for 200 Ids (<1sec). Not so great for 7000 unique Ids (7000 loops x 6 loops x enumerate lists). Takes around 40 seconds for every set of 6 CSV files.

My results will look like tuples: `[ [1,2,1,2,3,1] [5,7,3,2,9,8]...[8,5,4,3,5,2] ]`

Every entry in this list corresponds to the six individual CSV file values for every Unique ID.

Any suggestions for a more complicated list comprehension? Or am I silly using so many buffer apends? I'm fairly weak when it comes to comprehensions, but `(q for q, n in enumerate(total[y][i]) if str(n[0]) == str(unique[y][x]))` seems to be the key.

Many thanks.

Comment: What does your result look like? I can't quite picture it from your description.  I suspect that the answer to your problem will use dicts.

Comment: Thanks for replying! My results will look like tuples: [ [1,2,1,2,3,1] [5,7,3,2,9,8] etc ]. For every unique ID, this code above produces a list that contains six numbers - one number comes from each starting csv file (total[0][x]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are looking up the names by searching lists rather than by using dictionaries (or sets).  The basic plan is generally the same as what you have (get all of the names, then scan each file's data for attached values).

If I understand you correctly, here is one way to do it:

```
total =  [ [ ["Name", 6, 4.3],["Name2", 7, 5.5] ], [ ["Name3", 12, 5.7], ["Name4", 8, 9.2] ] ]
datasets = [ dict((row[0], row[1:]) for row in dataset) for dataset in total ]
for data in datasets:
    unique_names.update(data)

def CollectProteinInformation(datasets, unique_names):
    spectralcount = {}
    for name in unique_names:
        spectralcount[name] = [ data.get(name, [0.1])[0] for data in datasets ]

    return spectralcount
```

Comment: Brilliant solution, thank you. Gives me exactly what I need and performs very quickly. Thank you very much. +1